# Android no recive FCM Notificaciones Push cuando app está cerrada

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

cómo están?
Hace unos meses empecé a usar Notificaciones Push de FCM. El problema que tengo es que cuando la aplicación se encuentra cerrada, las notificaciones no llegan al dispositivo.

Desde el servidor el envío me devuelve un "success", como que la misma fue entregada. Les pasaré el código de la app para que me puedan ayudar con esto. Hace varios meses estoy tratando e intentado de todo para que solucionarlo. Espero alguna respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Android:

```java
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.accionait.canje365.R;
import com.accionait.canje365.activities.ChatActivity;
import com.accionait.canje365.activities.HomeActivity;
import com.accionait.canje365.constants.Constants;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        showNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Uri uriDefaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

         NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_notification)).getBitmap()))
            .setContentTitle("TITLE")
            .setContentText("MESSAGE")
            .setContentInfo("0")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker("Canje365")
            .setSound(uriDefaultSound);

         Intent home = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

         PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, home, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         builder.setContentIntent(intent);

         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Servidor:

```
var message = {
    to: token,
    data: {valor: 'test'}
};

fcm.send(message, function(err, response){  
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Notificacion enviada: ', response);
    }
});
```

Manifiest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.accionait.canje365">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service android:name=".sync.RunIntentService" />
    <service android:name=".sync.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".sync.FirebaseIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Bueno eso sería todo amigos. Espero que sea claro con mi código y pueda obtener una respuesta positiva. Nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: A lo ultimo que lei de Firebase aun tiene un problema con los push notification cuando la app esta suspendida

Comment: Que raro, porque hace varios meses dejo de estar en estado Beta. De todas maneras seguiremos esperando alguna respuesta.

Gracias de todas formas @MiguelOsorio

Comment: ¿Qué versión de google-services  tienes?

Comment: Bueno mejor si puedes añadir las dependencias de tu app/build.gradle

Comment: @JeCuRo Si, las dependencias las tengo agregada. Esta es la versión que estoy usando 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La aplicación es capaz de recibir notificaciones incluso estando 'muerta', si el token de ese dispositivo sigue activo y si las dependencias són correctas. Actualmente estoy usando:

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}
```

Y haciendo una simple simulación desde postman o firebase consola, me llegan las notificaciones, *upgradea* la dependencia y comprueba si funciona correctamente, si aún persiste el problema es que hay algo que se nos escapa. En un principio el servicio esta correctamente estructurado, así que parece que viene de las dependencias. Un saludo!

---

He estado leyendo por ahí y resulta que para que la bandeja del sistema reciba la notificación necesita el objeto *notification*, a continuación te dejo el JSON para que te hagas una idea:

```
{ "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "text": "5 to 1"
},
  "data": {
    "var1": "100",
    "var2": "1",
    "var3": "Aa"
  },
  "registration_ids" : ["",""]
}
```

El *To* que usas sólo permite mandar la notificación a un dispositivo, *registration_ids* te permite mandarlo a una array de dispositivos, *data* contiene los metadatos y *notification* contiene el título y el texto de esa notificación.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65097/discussion-on-answer-by-merli-escarpenter-perez-android-no-recive-fcm-notificaci).